# How to get parameter on server from POST Url

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying to hit some URL using Post Method  from client side with some data in the format of  "NameValuePair", And receive that data  from URL in servlet (server side) for performing some calculation and send back response to the client in JSON fromat.

But I am able to find correct data on Servlet (server)

Hit URL from Client Side

```
private void sendHTTPSPost() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/test/Registration";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "A"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", "12"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sex", "M"));

    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + 
                                response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());

}
```

On  Servlet

```
 @Override
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);   
    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();

    while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
       String paramName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
       System.out.println("Value of param  is ------------------"+paramName);
       String paramValue = request.getHeader(paramName);
       System.out.println("Value of key is ------------------"+paramValue);
  }

}
```

I tried a lot  but not get correct result.

Comment: Are you trying to get headers or request parameters?

Comment: I am Trying to get List value which i send with url

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
post.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the headers from the request you must use the request.getParameterNames() to get the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

requests.getParameter("name"); //returns A

requests.getParameter("age"); //returns 12

requests.getParameter("sex");  //returns M